# How to capture pop event in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm able to capture push event and control the navigation if my page has unsaved changes (`isDirty: true`) in `react-router-dom` v6 whereas I'm not able to wrap my head for pop event. Seems `navigator` from `NavigationContext` doesn't have pop event exposed directly to use. Can anyone help?

My Code for push event looks like this -

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const useConfirmExit = function (confirmExit: () => Promise<boolean>, when = true, callbackfn: (arg0: any) => void): void {
    const {navigator} = useContext(NavigationContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!when) {
            return () => { };
        }

        const {go, push} = navigator;

        navigator.push = async (...args: Parameters<typeof push>) => {
            const result = await confirmExit();
            if (result !== false) {
                callbackfn(arg0);
                push(...args);
            }
        };
        
        navigator.go = async (delta: number) => {
            const result = await confirmExit();
            if (result !== false) {
                go(delta);
            }
        };

        return () => {
            navigator.push = push;
            navigator.go = go;
        };
    }, [navigator, confirmExit, when]);
};
```

`confirmExit` is just another async function which is taking input of user if they want to navigate away from the unsaved page.

Comment: Are you just trying to "spy" on the `navigator` functions and augment their behavior, or do you need to listen for the window's PUSH and POP events?

Comment: Yes, I want to control the navigation if there are unsaved changes on the page and user is navigating to other page using some link or button. So, this particular code shows a modal to either save and continue or just cancel and stay on same page.

Comment: Related question, have you considered using the `useBlocker` hook? Here's a link to the official example: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/navigation-blocking

Comment: I'm not using data router. :) @DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese Now, If I want to invoke different methods to save my data from diff components in this particular piece of code, how I can do it? Like should I write a callback fn? ---> if (result !== false) { console.log('Save to be invoked'); push(...args); }

Comment: Yeah, a callback that is passed to this `useConfirmExit` hook that is called upon confirmation should work. Basically right where that `"Save to be invoked"` console log is located.

Comment: @DrewReese I modified the code in question but now I get error on this line - callbackfn(arg0); - Cannot find name arg0. Why? Is there I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, edits to posts to make quality improvements are welcome, but edits that fundamentally change what the code does are less welcome, especially since they can invalidate existing answers. It can make things confusing for future readers. It would be better to roll that edit back and create a new post for this specific function argument issue. If you do this you can ping me in a comment under my answer below and I can take a look.

Comment: Well, the issue here is that you've not declared any `arg0` variable in your hook ***to pass*** to the `callbackfn` function. You declared the type, e.g. `callbackfn: (arg0: any) => void`, but then you need to pass a value to the callback when it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`navigator`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/39ab0a8ee1873a307faee0f58ce0865e25caf619/packages/react-router/lib/context.ts#L99-L115) doesn't have any of the navigation actions, e.g. PUSH, POP, REPLACE, but it does have the `go` function to move forward/backward through the history stack. `navigator.go(-1)` is synonymous to a `goBack` or back navigation.

> ```
> /**
>  * A Navigator is a "location changer"; it's how you get to different locations.
>  *
>  * Every history instance conforms to the Navigator interface, but the
>  * distinction is useful primarily when it comes to the low-level <Router> API
>  * where both the location and a navigator must be provided separately in order
>  * to avoid "tearing" that may occur in a suspense-enabled app if the action
>  * and/or location were to be read directly from the history instance.
>  */
> export interface Navigator {
>   createHref: History["createHref"];
>   // Optional for backwards-compat with Router/HistoryRouter usage (edge case)
>   encodeLocation?: History["encodeLocation"];
>   go: History["go"];
>   push(to: To, state?: any, opts?: NavigateOptions): void;
>   replace(to: To, state?: any, opts?: NavigateOptions): void;
> }
> ```

You could augment the `go` function as well, something like the following:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from 'react-router-dom';

function useConfirmExit(confirmExit: () => Promise<boolean>, when = true): void {
  const { navigator } = useContext(NavigationContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!when) {
      return () => { };
    }

    const { go, push } = navigator;

    navigator.go = async (delta: number) => {
      const result = await confirmExit();
      if (result !== false) {
        console.log('Save to be invoked');
        go(delta);
      }
    };

    navigator.push = async (...args: Parameters<typeof push>) => {
      const result = await confirmExit();
      if (result !== false) {
        console.log('Save to be invoked');
        push(...args);
      }
    };
        
    return () => {
      navigator.go = go;
      navigator.push = push;
    };
  }, [navigator, confirmExit, when]);
}
```